# How to prevent printing of object id's to screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

How do I prevent a partial form in a view using HAML templating from rendering an object id?
For example, my `show.html.haml` for `Users` contains `=render 'shortlists'` for its list of shortlists:

```
%p
Shortlists:
= @shortlists.each do |s|
  = render :partial => 'shortlists', :locals => { :s => s }
%p
```

What I see on the screen is:

```
Shortlists:
 Shortlist A has 0 items
 Shortlist B has 5 items
"#<Shortlist:0xa95fa38>#<Shortlist:0xa95f54c>"
```

How do I prevent

```
"#<Shortlist:0xa95fa38>#<Shortlist:0xa95f54c>"
```

from rendering?

Comment: It would really help us if you added some code samples.

Comment: sure, here is the code inside my show.html.haml that renders the above:

Comment: %p
Shortlists:
= @shortlists.each do |s|
  = render :partial => 'shortlists', :locals => { :s => s }
%p

Comment: added in the original comment, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Change the `=` in front of `@shortlists.each` to a `-`.

[Relevant documentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_)

Comment: Or remove it entirely rather than replacing it with a "-". What you were doing was printing to screen the result of the block, which is the list of @shortlists.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense the code even more:

```
# view.html.haml
= render @shortlists
```

Then, in `_shortlist.html.haml` the instance of `Shortlist` for the current iteration will be accessible through the variable named `shortlist`